# "Who lives there?" vs "Who live there?"

Tags: grammar

I'm a bit confused as to the proper grammar when posing the following question.

"Who lives there?" <- seems to imply just one person
"Who live there?" <- seems to imply more than one person
Also this: 1. "Who worships you?" 2. "Who worship you?"

Which would be grammatically correct?

Comment: I won't be able to answer better than this person did: https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/31139/76031. TL;DR, Who is typically assumed singular unless otherwise specified.

Comment: With the slight addition that even if you *know* there are multiple people living in a house, you still use the singular in the short sentence construction you provided. (But, with a different sentence construction, you could ask something like "*Who are all of those people who **live** there?*")

Comment: @rosslh -- I have never heard the *optional plural override* as described in that ELL answer.

Answer (score 1):

"Who lives there?" and "Who worships you?" are the correct forms.  When you're asking a simple "who" question (like the examples you give) or a simple "what" question (like "What made those holes in the ground?"), the verb in the question defaults to its third-person singular form, because the person(s) or thing(s) referred to by the interrogative pronoun ("who" or "what") are lumped together and asked about as a whole.

For instance:

"Who lives there?" - This sentence is asking about the entire group (of residents of the residence) *as a collective unit*.  Hence, the verb "to live" adopts the third-person singular form ("lives").

In contrast:

"Which people live there?" - This sentence is asking about the individual members of the group *separately from each other*.  Hence, the verb "to live" adopts the third-person plural form ("live").

"Who" and "what", in the absence of evidence to the contrary, are assumed to refer to the group as a whole.  When referring to the members of the group as individual, separate units, "which" is a better choice.

Here's a little drawing I whipped up to help show the difference:

[image: drawing showing that "who" refers to the inhabitants as a whole, whereas "which" refers to the inhabitants as separate entities]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct depending on the context. Is the person suggesting/asking  there are more than one person living at the property or suggesting a person lives there?

Comment: If the core of your 'answer' is a question, then it probably shouldn't be in the answer box.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/431090)